# Precisely IP geolocation

Tags: php, geolocation, ip

Can I get users latitude and longitude with 6 digits after decimal point from his IP (like 52.229676 and 21.012229)? I've already tried some Geo-IP services but it gave me only 4 digits after decimal point.

Comment: IP != location. ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP geolocation provides city level accuracy and not street level. Therefore, there is no reason you want to get 6 decimal compare to existing decimal because the location is usually central of the city.

If you need high precision, you will need to get the coordinates from GPS. However, it required end user permission before you can access this information.

Answer (score 0):

IP Geolocation doesn't have the 6 decimals accuracy. If you need this precision you have to use some GPS-based solution.

If you need one solution more precise, [IP Vigilante](https://www.ipvigilante.com) has 5 decimals of accuracy. You can take a look at this JSON output example https://ipvigilante.com/8.8.8.8 and in the documentation https://www.ipvigilante.com/api-developer-docs/

Disclosure: I am the developer of [IP Vigilante](https://www.ipvigilante.com).